# What's the name of the current settlement?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How to find the name of the current settlement? The Dwarven name is in the civilizations screen ("Imports from ..."), but I can't see the translation anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's on the Z-Stocks Screen.

[image]

Alas, no freehand circles.